# Как определить panel в начале z списка или нет?

Tags: c#

Как определить panel в начале z списка или нет?

```
Panel.BringToFront();
```

поднимает ее в верх z списка, а как определить вверху она или нет?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213340/5045688

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!